# Skipping a text line if the line is empty in tensorflow

Tags: string, tensorflow, iterator

I would like to process a text file containing sentences.
Each sentence is stored as a each line of that text file. I would like to retrieve each line using an iterator as follows:

```
class Reader(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_name)
        self._iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    def next_line(self):
        # What I want to do is skipping blank lines here.
        return self._iterator.get_next()
```

However, if the line is an empty line, I would like to skip that line. What would be the best way of implementing this skipping? I would like to implement that functionality in the above `next_line` method.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to apply [filter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter) to dataset.

```py
filter(lambda line:tf.not_equal(tf.strings.length(line),0))
```

Suppose your data are as follows：

```py
1
2,2
3,3,3

5,5,5
6,6,6
```

An example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset('a.csv').filter(lambda line:tf.not_equal(tf.strings.length(line),0))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

while True:
    try:
        print(iterator.get_next())
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break
```

The result:

```py
tf.Tensor(b'1', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'2,2', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'3,3,3', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'5,5,5', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'6,6,6', shape=(), dtype=string)
```